# Show message in view on a condition in grails

Tags: grails

I have a action from login page which is being used to login. Now I want to show a message under the form in the login page and then redirect it. But I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone please help me on this ? Here is my view page and controller given below :

view >>>

```
<form id="login_form" controller="login" action="loginAction">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">User Name : </td>
      <td><g:textField name="username" id="username" required="true"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Password : </td>
      <td> <g:passwordField name="password" id="password" required="true"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Log-In"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

controller action >>>

```
def loginAction = {
    def username = params?.username
    def password = params?.password
    def user = User.findByUsername(username)
    def pass = User.findByPassword(password)
    if(user && pass){
        redirect(controller:"home",action:"home")
    }else{
        redirect(controller:"login",action:"login")
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful! There is also a bug in your code. It will log-in a user who enters a valid username and password, even if the password belongs to a **different** user! Try: `def user = User.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password)` and then `if(user) // redirect to 'home'`

Comment: @David thank you so much. I have applied it. Infact I was think is my idea is a good idea !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your meessage in Flash scope like,

```
flash.message = message(code: "login.failed")
```

and after put your redirection code

```
redirect(action: "login", params: [])
```

on view check for flash message availability,

```
  <g:if test="${flash.message}">
    <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
  </g:if>
```

I hope I got your question right, please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: yes it is helpful. But I just took your line flash and the gsp page's side. thank you so much. I am accepting as perfect answere although there is a little problem which is that when I press the back page button in the browser it contains the failed message in gsp. Can you help me on this ?